# Reuse an angular 1 module in NativeScript angular 2 app

Tags: angularjs, angular, nativescript, ng-upgrade

I would like to reuse an angular 1 module in a NativeScript - angular 2 app.

I have read about the upgrade module and its `UpgradeAdapter` service in [angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#upgrading-with-the-upgrade-adapter).

> [...] service that can bootstrap and manage hybrid applications that support both Angular 2 and Angular 1 code.

In order to use the `UpgradeAdapter` service, its [`bootstrap`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/upgrade/index/UpgradeAdapter-class.html#!#bootstrap-anchor) function should be called.

Knowing that NativeScript also requires to call a bootstrap function [`nativeScriptBootstrap`](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/v0.3.0/nativescript-angular/application.ts#L175), I am wondering if it exposes a way to use the `UpgradeAdapter` bootstrap instead of the standard angular 2 one.

**Edit:** I created [an issue in their github repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/438).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No support for Angular 1 module is planned as stated in this [comment](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/438#issuecomment-248575202) from nativescript-angular contributor.

> We never intended to support Angular 1 components, and I doubt we'll allocate resources for it in the foreseeable future.
>
> That said, there is no problem for support for the UpgradeAdapter come from a separate library developed by the community. We'll consider PR's that make it easy for such a library to do its job.

Answer (score 3):

I might be a bit off but here is what I know about NativeScript + Angular 2. NativeScript takes advantage of the way the Angular 2 framework is build, mainly the decoupled renderer. NativeScript has its own angular renderer which handles the native rendering of the elements, meaning that if you have lets say an `<Label text="simple label"></Labe>` element in your Angular Component's template it is rendered to the native iOS `UILabel` and Android `TextView`. This is only possible for Angular 2 since it allows the NativeScript team to write its own rendered and pass it to the Angular 2 framework.

Hope this makes sense in how and why Angular 1 Components might not be supported even with the mentioned `UpgradeAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand the issue about the components. However, I am wondering if it is possible to re-use angular services, filters, etc. The point is that I have an angular 1 module (library-like) which has mainly services that I want to re-use.

Comment: This is an interesting question indeed, I would recommend to check the nativescript-angular github repo's (https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues) issues for such information or ask it there also.